# How to install Oracle OC4J on Mac

Tags: eclipse, macos, oc4j

I am using Eclipse to create a Java EE project and need "Oracle OC4J Standalone 10.1.3.n run time".

How do I install it on my Mac?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would recommend installing virtal box and use oracle VM. Find more information at https://tech.lds.org/wiki/Oracle_VM